# Is there any other way to fetch the gmail contacts?

Tags: php, curl

I found the curl not working after all possible ways of debugging mentioned in php.net 
Even then the curl doesnt seems to work for me
Is there any other method to import the contacts fronm gmail to php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an API for that, use it: http://code.google.com/apis/contacts/

Edit: already available libraries: http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata